# how to install Diagnostic plugin for cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

i am new to cordova and android.

i wanted to install [Diagnostic plugin](https://github.com/adityashankert/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Diagnostic) for android but he wants me to add

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-X.X.X.js"></script>
```

where can i find this js file?

can someone please help me with this issue

Comment: https://github.com/adityashankert/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/Android/Diagnostic/www/diagnostic.js